# How can I connect a USB device to my PC wirelessly?

Tags: wireless-bridge

I'm re asking the question, can I connect my USB camera to my Laptop wirelessly? Power at the camera end is no problem and the distance is about 6 or 7 feet. It's for a connection between my Telescope camera and my nearby laptop computer.
Thanks

Comment: If its that short of a distance, why not get a cable that will cost a few dollars and be less of a headache in the long run?

Comment: Black cables strung between scope and computer outside in the middle of the night presents a problem. Maybe there's no other solution.

Comment: creepy to run into the exact question I was asking... for the exact same reason.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few wireless USB hubs out there but they don't work very well. Toshiba made a wireless version of their DynaDock port replicator but it looks like that has been discontinued: [Toshiba Dynadock Wireless U Universal USB Docking Station](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002Q8HMWS)

There is another one by Iogear that is available for purchase on Amazon: [IOGEAR Wireless 4-Port USB Sharing Station GUWIP204](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000UU46W8)

I want to stress that the range will be limited, the connection will be unstable, and I imagine that some devices will not work at all.